# Text and image half half, aligned next to each other

Tags: html, css

Example: https://gyazo.com/8d717ee1a21ed49033deece5a105239d  (Photoshop).
Black = Slider, Grey = Image, White = Textarea with changeable background color.

I also want to make this responsive to phone devices and such, but that doesn't work either, if I just take an image that is half's the page widht and a height.

I am trying to align an image to the left and the text exactly in a container next to it with the background of the text changeable. I tried using the properties left: ; Right: ;, margins and paddings but that doesn't work.

The image and text should be underneath the div called A3L_Slogan and A3L_Catchphrase. I hope anyone can point me out in  the good direction.

Below you can find a JS fiddle without any of that code in it

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo-box {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.logo-box a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}
.logo-box img {display: block;}
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #868686;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  background: #868686;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}
nav a:hover:after {width: 100%;}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  header {text-align: center;}
  .logo-box {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  }
  ul {float: none;}
  nav li:first-of-type {margin-left: 0;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
nav {overflow: visible;}
nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
nav li:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
nav a:after {content: none;}
}
.A3L_Slogan, .slideshow{
  position: relative;
}
.slideshow{
    height: 600px;
}
.fadein img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 600px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

.A3L_Slogan {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.slogan_title {
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slogan_catchphrase {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .slideshow{
      height: 300px;
  }
  .fadein img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 300px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .slideshow{
      height: 200px;
  }
  .fadein img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 200px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    max-width: 270px;
  }
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 4000);
  });
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-box">
          <a href="/">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Forums</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Rules</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Monetization</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sign-up</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="fadein">
        <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-159465.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-160434.png" alt="">
        <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-150988.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A3L_Slogan">
      <div class="slogan_title">
        Hardcore Roleplay Community
      </div>
      <div class="slogan_catchphrase">
        The next level roleplay experience
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your image and text in a container such as:

```
 <div class="container-row">

    <div class="hero-image">
      <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-159465.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="A3L_Slogan">
      <div class="slogan_title">
        Hardcore Roleplay Community
      </div>
      <div class="slogan_catchphrase">
        The next level roleplay experience
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and you can use flexbox to align the items

```
.container-row{
  display: flex;
}

.container-row .hero-image{
  flex: 1;
}

.container-row .A3L_Slogan {
  flex: 2;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I've tried that and that doesn't seem to work. It only makes the image full width. the A3L Slogan div should stay where it is as well, it should be underneath that slogan, with different text and titles.

Comment: you'll have to set the width for your image.

Comment: For responsiveness, would it be best to set the max width in css or in the img part itself?

Comment: You can do that with [flexbox responsive images](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Kgofa), read more about flexbox. so you don't need to write media queries.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work. The only problem now is that the text is not alligned properly with each others. Also when I test the responsiveness, the text just vanishes behind the image and doesn't go underneath the image